# How do I use a boolean on my model that wraps a string value from the database?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

Weird question, and there may not be an answer... I inherited an old mysql database where unfortunately many of the "boolean" fields were set up as VARCHAR instead of the more appropriate TINYINT(1)...

I'm now running Entity Framework Core on top of the database.  Since I don't know everywhere the boolean values are used, I can't update the database quite yet, but I would like to be able to actually work with the string values as booleans in EF... **Is there a way to change the model types so the model wraps up everything neatly as bool but it still treats the fields as strings when I push it to the database?**

Essentially, in my code, I want to be able to do this:
    `object.IsGood = true;`
Instead of this: `object.IsGood = "TRUE"`

And my model would just discreetly handle the value conversion, something like this for writing to the database (and I'd need another converter for reading the boolean values back from the database):

```
string databaseValue = "";
if (object.IsGood)
{
  databaseValue = "TRUE";
}
else
{
  databaseValue = "FALSE";
}
```

Any way I can see of doing it, I'd be actually changing the database when I change the model... I know I could wrap the model itself into another class, but that seems confusing. I'd love to just update the database, but that could be a huge pain to unravel all the possible places that code touches these values... so I was hoping there was an intermediate solution.

Comment: I do not know EF in detail, but I asume it has some way to map DB values to Model values. Including custom mappings. This should fall under that.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head... it seems silly now, but I wasn't looking for the right term... a quick search for "Custom Value Mapping" brought up what I was looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

Comment: add a column with a `TINYINT` datatype and simply run a `UPDATE  ... SET tinyint_column = varchar_column` ...   do a check and drop the varchar column and rename the tinyint column...Should work also p.s do it on test data/table first..

Comment: I know and understand how to run the value updates on the database, sorry if that wasn't clear... I'm avoiding doing that immediately because if I make the change without first updating the code then it will break the code... so I first need to find the code that uses it, and that will take a long time... so it's easier to set up the converted in EF in the mean time so I don't have to change more code later.

Comment: Maybe using a MySQL View might be better, then the conversion layer is in the database, meaning less code in the application to change after the conversion.. i ám assuming here  entity-framework-core works with a source table param/variable in the models?  ..

Comment: The view is definitely another good solution.  I think it's a toss up as to which is less work (the view vs EF value conversion).  I don't have enough experience with EF myself to really say if there are downsides to the value conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always search for this type of thing under the terms "mapping" or "wrapper" and those were not bringing up anything from the documentation that seemed useful... Christopher's comment got me on the right track and I got what I was searching for.

Apparently "**Value Conversions**" are what I was looking for:
[Value Conversions EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions)

Edit: I've removed the docs example since anyone can look that up.  I'm adding my real example below.

Since I wanted to convert back and forth between a string and a boolean, I created this converter as a static value so I could reuse it in a couple of models:

```
public static class EntityFrameworkCoreValueConverters
{
    /// <summary>
    /// converts values stored in the database as VARCHAR to a nullable bool
    /// handles "TRUE", "FALSE", or DBNULL
    /// </summary>
    public static ValueConverter<bool?, string> dbVarCharNullableToBoolNullableConverter = new ValueConverter<bool?, string>(
        v => v == true ? "TRUE" : v == false ? "FALSE" : null,
        v => v.ToUpper() == "TRUE" ? true : false
    );
}
```

Note that there already exists a `BoolToStringConverter` as part of the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion` namespace, but this doesn't appear to handle null values, which I needed.

Then I can change my model values to `bool?` instead of `string`, but leave alone the actual database value types.

The `dbVarCharNullableToBoolNullableConverter` can then be applied in my `OnModelCreating` method (or in my case `Configure` on the model itself which gets applied in the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MachineHelpRequests> builder)
        {
            //... model builder code above

            builder.Property(e => e.IsAcknowledged)
                .HasColumnName("acknowledged_mhr")
                .HasColumnType("varchar(45)")
                .HasConversion(EntityFrameworkCoreValueConverters.dbVarCharNullableToBoolNullableConverter);

            //... model builder code below
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right.  I went back and made some edits to include the actual code I am now using.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the best solution but it might get you by until you can refactor the DB.

Add a partial class to the Model and implement the appropriate getters and setters.

```
partial class Model
{
    [NotMapped]
    public bool FieldABool
    {
        get
        {
            return FieldA == "TRUE";
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == true)
            {
                    FieldA = "TRUE";
            }         
            else
            {
                FieldA = "FALSE";
            }
        }
    }
}
```